# Template function gets called instead of function of base type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization, c++03

I have a class hierarchy that can be written to an object using `operator<<`. The example looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
};

struct Shift
{
    template< typename U >
    Shift& operator<<(const U&)
    {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Shift& operator<<(const Base&)
    {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

#if 0
    Shift& operator<<(const Derived&)
    {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
#endif
};

int main()
{
    Shift sh;
    Base bas;
    Derived der;
    int u32 = 0;

    sh << bas;
    sh << der;
    sh << u32;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const Base&)
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const U&) [with U = Derived]
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const U&) [with U = int]
```

If I uncomment the `#if 0` section it will change to the desired output:

```
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const Base&)
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const Derived&)
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const U&) [with U = int]
```

I have a lot of derived classes (actually a whole hierarchy) and until now I have to write a separate definition of `operator<<` for all those types. What I'd like is to have a solution where the operator for the base type is called for all types that are derived from `Base`. Is that possible?

P.S.: I tried several solutions, for example writing a helper class:

```
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
};

template< typename T >
struct Helper
{
    static void shift()
    {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template< >
struct Helper< Base >
{
    static void shift()
    {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Shift
{
    template< typename U >
    Shift& operator<<(const U& value)
    {
        Helper< U >::shift();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Output:

```
static void Helper<Base>::shift()
static void Helper<T>::shift() [with T = Derived]
static void Helper<T>::shift() [with T = int]
```

But still the base template is called, instead of the `Base` specialization.

P.P.S.: I'm currently limited to `C++03` without `Boost`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your current implementation the templated overload is preferred as per §13.3.3.1.4 [over.ics.ref]/p1:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a *derived-to-base Conversion* (13.3.3.1).

Since the *derived-to-base Conversion* is given a *Conversion* rank, to achieve the desired output the templated version with an *identity* conversion rank must be excluded from the set of viable functions during the overload resolution by using `enable_if` with a proper condition (SFINAE):

```
#include <type_traits>

//...
template <typename U>
auto operator<<(const U&)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Base, U>{}, Shift&>::type
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

Shift& operator<<(const Base&)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Output:

```
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const Base&)
Shift& Shift::operator<<(const Base&)
typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_base_of<Base, U>{}), Shift&>::type Shift::operator<<(const U&) [with U = int; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_base_of<Base, U>{}), Shift&>::type = Shift&]
```

---

In [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) the implementation is less readable:

```
template <bool B, typename T = void>
struct enable_if { typedef T type; };
template <typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> {};
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct is_base_of
{
    typedef char (&yes)[1];
    typedef char (&no)[2];
    static yes test(Base*);
    static no test(...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(test((Derived*)0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
const bool is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value;

//...
template <typename U>
typename enable_if<!is_base_of<Base, U>::value, Shift&>::type operator<<(const U&)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

Shift& operator<<(const Base&)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This sounds great! Unfortunately I forgot to mention I'm constrained to C++03. I'll update my question ... maybe I can convince my co-workers to C++11 now! :)

Comment: @hochl the same effect can be achieved in C++03

Comment: Cool! :) Can you show a `C++03` version please? It seems `type_traits` was only introduced with `C++11` ... :(

Comment: @hochl are you using Boost or shall I include hand-written traits?

Comment: Unfortunately `Boost` is not an option either ... sorry for the hassle!

Comment: Ok I'll try to wrap my head around your answer, I think this will take some minutes :P

Comment: Sheesh it works! Great! Thanks for your answer ... I must admit I didn't totally understand all of it, I'll have to dig into that now ;) Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: @hochl the key-word to understand this is "*SFINAE*"

Comment: Ok I understood it but one thing: Why is it ` = void` in the first line? I can't see the use case for it (or there is a gap in my understanding ^^).

Comment: @hochl just to make it similar to the official implementation from `<type_traits>`